# Can I javadoc a whole Java project from the command line without explicitly naming packages?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a java codebase with many packages which I'm not that familiar with.

I just want to get an overview by javadoc-ing the while thing. Without having to specify the names of which packages I want to document. I just want "everything"

Is there a simple command line option for this?

Update :

I would have just expected to be able to write something like

```
javadoc -d /home/html -sourcepath .
```

to get all the packages defined under the currect directory

But it doesn't seem to work that way. But what would be the way to get that?

Comment: Did you try `Open in IntelliJ` ->`Tools` -> `Generate JavaDoc`?

Comment: The question was about CLI, not IntelliJ.

Comment: Well, how is that code base organized? It for sure has a default build environment, right?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Sorry, didn't notice.

Comment: @interstar See [the Java8 JavaDoc examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDJBGFC)

Answer (score 1):

## GUI based answer, unrelated

An easy and cozy way (requires [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)):

1. Open the project.
   [image: IntelliJ window image]
2. Open the `Tools` menu.
   [image: Image showing Menu]
3. Click on `Generate JavaDoc...`.
   [image: Image showing highlighted option]
4. In JavaDoc Scope, choose the `Whole project` radiobutton.
   [image: Image with JavaDoc options]

Comment: Hint: when a large code base isn't setup to be used with Intellij ... there is a good chance that "open the project" isn't as simple as you depict it here.

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's question - "Is there a simple command line option for this?"

Comment: I'd be interested to know if generating that actually helps much

Comment: The OP said command line not IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is in `C:\JavaProject` and the source files are in `C:\JavaProject\src`,

Use command:

```
cd C:\JavaProject\src
```

followed by:

```
javadoc -d C:\JavaProject\docs * -subpackages *
```

**Warning**:
This method will fail if it encounters a subdirectory that is not a package or source.
It will also fail if files are present in `src` or if a directory is empty with the message `error - No source files for package`.

Here's a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kitswas/javadoc-experiments) for you to clone and try this out.

Comment: Problem with this is that it blows up if it hits a subdirectory that ISN'T a package. I want to recurse down from where I am and build javadoc for any directories that are java packages, but ignore other dirs

Comment: @interstar I still think using an IDE to accomplish this is easier. Good luck.

Comment: Is that a way of saying you think it can't be done on the command line?

Comment: `-subpackages *` is not doing what you seem to think. Use `-subpackages ""` when your current directory is the source directory or in conjunction with the `-sourcepath` option.

Comment: Added a repo for testing but there a lot of conditions where the command fails.

Comment: @Holger Tried both `-subpackages *` and `-subpackages ""` on the demo repo. Git shows no changes expect the timestamp.

Comment: I have no idea what you expect from Git. `-subpackages ""` will not fail on empty subdirectories or non-java files because it does the intended thing, process all packages (technically, all packages starting with an empty string). That’s why it also works correctly with `-sourcepath`. In contrast, when using `-subpackages *`, *the `*` gets expanded to all elements of the current directory* and only happens to do the right thing when there is exactly one element, a directory for the top level package. Even a trivial case like having `com` and `org` in the directory will fail.

Comment: @Holger "I have no idea what you expect from Git" - I wanted to see the differences between the generated files.  Thank you for the explanation. **Please** [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72086792/edit) this answer or create one of your own to share this knowledge in a more prominent manner.